# "swinging" action on text using css and jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to emulate text "hanging" off a bar and swinging when hovered over. Here's the JSfiddle for the code that I've currently got: http://jsfiddle.net/VRTAf/. As you can see, there is no change in the rotation on hover. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code.

HTML:

```
<div id="chandelier">
                <nav>
                    <ul id="chandelier-list">
                        <li id="logo-home"><a href="#home" class="scrollPage">home</a></li>
                        <li id="logo-about"><a href="#about" class="scrollPage">about us</a></li>
                        <li id="logo-range"><a href="#range" class="scrollPage">our range</a></li>
                        <li id="logo-contact"><a href="#contact" class="scrollPage">contact us</a></li>
                        <li id="logo-blog"><a href="#blog" class="scrollPage">blog</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
#chandelier nav ul li {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    writing-mode: lr-tb;

    -webkit-transform-origin: right top;
    -moz-transform-origin: right top;
    -ms-transform-origin: right top;
    -o-transform-origin: right top;
    transform-origin: right top;

    font-size: 18px;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.swing1 { -webkit-transform: rotate(-80deg); -moz-transform: rotate(-80deg); -o-transform: rotate(-80deg); transform: rotate(-80deg); }
.swing2 { -webkit-transform: rotate(-97deg); -moz-transform: rotate(-97deg); -o-transform: rotate(-97deg); transform: rotate(-97deg); }
.swing3 { -webkit-transform: rotate(-85deg); -moz-transform: rotate(-85deg); -o-transform: rotate(-85deg); transform: rotate(-85deg); }
.swing4 { -webkit-transform: rotate(-92deg); -moz-transform: rotate(-92deg); -o-transform: rotate(-92deg); transform: rotate(-92deg); }
.swing5 { -webkit-transform: rotate(-89deg); -moz-transform: rotate(-89deg); -o-transform: rotate(-89deg); transform: rotate(-89deg); }

#logo-home { top: 0; left: -32px; }
#logo-about { top: 0; left: -17px; }
#logo-range { top: 0; left: 14px; }
#logo-contact { top: 0; left: 48px; }
#logo-blog { top: 0; left: 135px; }

#chandelier nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#chandelier nav ul { 
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#chandelier nav ul li').hover(
function () {
    $(this).addClass('swing1');
    $(this).addClass('swing2');
    $(this).addClass('swing3');
    $(this).addClass('swing4');
    $(this).addClass('swing5');
},
function () {
    $(this).removeClass('swing5');
}
);
```

Comment: You've not included the link to jsfiddle :)

Comment: Opps, sorry. Just added it now.

Comment: Is [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/VRTAf/7/) what you are looking for?

Comment: That's better much better than what I had (i.e. it actually rotates when hovered), but I was trying to get it to swing back and forth. On your example, it only seems to be enacting "swing2" - maybe I have to put a delay between the two..

Comment: @babbaggeii: yes, that is one way. But if you are targeting only modern browsers (those that support CSS3 animation), I would recommend doing this with `keyframes` instead. Coming back to the question, I am still wondering how changing `#chandelier nav ul li` to `.swing` worked :P